# How to filter a Parse query by an tableview index?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a UITableViewController in my application. In this Table i am performing this Parse Query:

```
-(IBAction)joinEvent:(id)sender {


PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
[query selectKeys:@[@"Vacants"]];
[query whereKey:@"Username" equalTo:PFUser.currentUser.username];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects


        for (NSObject *object in objects){

            NSString *a = [object valueForKey:@"Vacants"];
            NSLog(@"vacants %@", a);


        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

}

This query gets me all the vacants in my parse cloud.

What i want is to be able to just get the vacants for a certain IndexPath.row of my table.

So far I have tried to use the

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

instead of the IBAction, but still the same result. But using this approach i don't know how to call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath from the IBAction, which i believe it would solve my issue.

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *cellID = @"cell";

TFGResultsTableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TFGResultsTableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:cellID];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.eventnamelabel.text = [eventnameArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

cell.userLabel.text = [userArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
cell.sportLabel.text = [sportArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
cell.eventDateLabel.text = [dateArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
cell.eventHourLabel.text = [hourArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
cell.eventPlaceLabel.text = [placeArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
cell.vacantsLabel.text = [vacantsArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
cell.cityLabel.text = [cityArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

if([cell.sportLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Soccer" ]){

    cell.eventImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SoccerBallIcon.png"];
}
else{

    cell.eventImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: What is in your table view? The index alone means nothing...

Comment: Do you want to query particular indexed data from your parse cloud?

Comment: My tableviewcontroller was created using storyboards so, in order to refer to my tableview, i just do a [self.tableview XXX];

Comment: Thats right rajram !

Comment: You want to select the data in the tableview's particular index that was allocated from your parse cloud. Right?

Comment: Thats correct again rajam :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the data from the parse server to a *global Array* and *set the delegate for the table view via code or in soryboard.*

```
NSArray *copyArray = objects;
yourtableview.delegate = self ;
```

In your delegateMethod-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     NSString *a = [[copyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Vacants"];
}
```

Comment: My question is Why in a NSArray when what I want i retrieve is a NSString?

Comment: Show me your **- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}** datasource method.

Comment: +1,  Seems like a lot of iOS-parse developers are using the same bit of sample code that tries to extract an array of strings from the retrieved objects.  One column of the retrieved data is almost always less useful than all of it.

Comment: You already using an array to allocate data in cell, then why are not using the same array in  **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method.