# Presenting correct View Controller instance depending on cell selection in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, didselectrowatindexpath

I understand this might be covered in parts in answers to other questions (see references) I've seen on the site, but due to my limited experience I haven't been able to understand each part as it relates to my code. Please forgive me for any duplications.

I have a PFQueryTableViewController (essentially a UITableViewController) called `threadsViewController` that sources cell information from a Parse backend. The table view consists of threads similar to what you would see on a web forum.

I then have a separate class `postsViewController` which is another PFQueryTableViewController that I wish to display a table of all the responses ('posts') to that particular thread.

The functionality I'm looking for is for a user tapping on a thread (left screen in the image) to be presented with a `postsViewController` (right screen) containing only those posts/responses related to that thread. (See basic diagram below).

[image: Desired table view action]

**What I do know from my research:**

- The Parse backend is established with classes for **Thread** and **Post**.
- I'm probably going to use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method

**What I need help with:**

- How can I know which thread cell a user tapped on, and then pass that on so that the `postsViewController` only displays posts from that Thread?
- A layman's description of how to use `indexPath.row` etc

I understand how to complete PFQueries etc to get the data for the cells, I just don't know how to implement the navigation and how to tell `postsViewController` which posts to show.

In case it helps somehow, here is my implementation so far. I have tried addign a property to the `postsViewController` called `fromThread` to somehow store the thread but apart from that I'm out of ideas!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    postsViewController *postsVC = [[postsViewController alloc] init];
    postsVC.fromThread = //?
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"threadsToPosts" sender:self];
}
```

**References**

[How to filter a Parse query by an tableview index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390540/how-to-filter-a-parse-query-by-an-tableview-index)

[Pass Index Number between UITableView List segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166509/pass-index-number-between-uitableview-list-segue)

[didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321433/didselectrowatindexpath-and-prepareforsegue-implementation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  You need know how to do two things: (1) access your parse objects by `indexPath`, and (2) push a new view controller in a navigation controller.

(1) is simpler: `PFQueryTableVC` provides a method called [`objectAtIndexPath:`](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/objectAtIndexPath:) that does just what you need.

```
// indexPath is the indexPath parameter to the didSelectRow delegate method
PFObject *fromThread = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

(2) is simple, too. But more complicated because there are a couple ways to do it.  [Segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html) is the more modern way, but I think the old way is simpler, and certainly easier to describe in code. View Controllers are given storyboard ids on the "Identity" tab in the storyboard editor.  Give your Posts-presenting VC a storyboard id like "PostVC".

To get a new instance, use that storyboard id as follows:

```
MyPostVC *postVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PostVC"];
// initialize it with the PFObject we got above
postVC.fromThread = fromThread;

// present it on the navigation stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:postVC animated:YES];
```

And `fromThread` is just what the `PostVC` will need to form a query for posts associated with the selected thread.

Comment: You're a scholar and a gentleman. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data of cell to next ViewController in `prepareForSegue` with something like this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"threadsToPosts"]) {
        UINavigationController *navCon = segue.destinationViewController;
        postsViewController *postsViewController = [navCon.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        // Whatever you are populating your tableView with
        Thread *thread = [self.thread objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
        postsViewController.thread = thread;
    }
}
```